# Getting variables updates inside a function (Telegram bot, Python3, python-telegram-bot library, multiprocessing)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a telegram bot with https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot library in python3.

I want to make the bot send me infos from a dictionary that will be updated later on. This is my code now:

```
from secret import botToken
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def f(dicts):
    dicts['runNumber'] = 1


def runUp(dicts):
    dicts['runNumber'] += 1


############################# Telegram Bot part #################################


logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def botStart(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text("Hey ! do /help or /test ")


def test(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /test is issued."""
    runUp(d)
    update.message.reply_text("run number is now : {0}".format(d['runNumber']))

def help(update, context):

    """Send a message when the command /help is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text("HELP !!")

def echo(update, context):
    """Send a message when message without command is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text("echo")


def error(update, context):
    """Log Errors caused by Updates."""
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)


def main():
    """Start the bot."""

    updater = Updater(botToken, use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", botStart))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("test", test))

    # on noncommand i.e message - answer in telegram
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, echo))

    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()
#################################################################################



if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()

    d = manager.dict()

    p1 = Process(target=f, args=(d,))
    p1.start()
    p1.join()

    p2 = Process(target=main)
    p2.start()
```

but everytime I run the /test command i get this feedback from the logging in the python window:

```
... caused error "name 'd' is not defined"
```

Note : I can't do without the multiprocessing since it is used somewhere else in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `test(update, context)`, `d` is really not defined (it is present in code but not visible from the `test` method). You need to explicitly use `d` as a global variable or add it as a parameter of the function `test` (and it callers).

Comment: You can use ``bold`` or others to enhance your text format. check [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)